# Inconsistent percentage margin calculation for absolutely positioned item

Tags: css, margin, css-position, safari

I have a situation where I have a 'bottom' content div within a general container. This div should stay at the bottom (with absolute positioning), but have a percentage gap to base of the container. The percentage should be relative to the width of the container.

We can't use 'bottom:5%' because [as the position props define](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props) this is relative to the height. How about margin? Yes! It works in Chrome .. and Firefox. Ah, but not in Safari. It seems Chrome and Safari calculate it based on the container width and Safari on the container height.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gxSk/6/) in Chrome and Safari and you'll see the inconsistency. CSS styles:

```
.container {
    background: #990000;
    width: 345px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.bottom {
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Anybody know where the bug lies here - with Safari? Chrome/Firefox? The spec?

A quick check shows that padding might work consistently, but it's not ideal for those who would want to use margin (i.e. when a background comes into play).

Comment: I don't see a problem in Safari/Chrome/Firefox on Windows7

Comment: Mac: 10.8.2 , Chrome: 27.0.1453.93 , Safari: 6.0.2 (8536.26.17)

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with Safari. W3C Standards state that margins that are defined using percentages should be calculated *with respect to the width of the containing block* (not the height).

Check it: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/box.html#margin-properties

So basically, you're stuck with the bug. However, I'd suggest using some JS to target Safari, get the width of the container and apply a margin as a percentage of that width.

**For example:**

```
    var width = $('.container').width();    // get the width of div.container
    var bottomMargin = width * 0.05;       // multiply the width by 0.05 to get 5% of the container width

    // look to see if the browser is Safari
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {                  
        $('.bottom').css('margin-bottom', bottomMargin+'px');   // apply our margin to div.bottom
    }
    else {
    };;
```

I had some trouble implementing this in JS Fiddle so have created a page **[here](http://www.indieweb.co.nz/testing/safari-bottom-margin-percentage.html)**.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Android Browsers and was able to solve it by putting the margin on a child element.

```
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.bottom-child {
    height:100%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    background: #000;
}
```

The key is not to put the margin on the absolutely positioned element.